# Representing an sparse matrix in Java using linked lists

Tags: java, sparse-matrix

I'm making a little program to make a representation of sparse matrixes (a matrix with a lot of elements equal to zero). Represented like [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=gMcmb-qYODUC&lpg=PR3&dq=roberto%20florez%20algoritmos&hl=es&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q&f=false) page 108 (I think watching at the figure is enough to understand it) it is using linked lists.

[*Don't read this paragraph if you understand the figure*]
It must store only elements different of zero, save the row and the column of the element, and link them as follows. First element of the matrix must have the dimensions of it; it is linked to a node that represents the first row that has an element different of zero and that element is linked to two nodes: the element of the matrix itself (links at the right) and the next row that has an element different of zero. That way, the entire matrix is constructed.

Ok I'm having problems thinking about the variables of each class. I have two: `Node` and `Matrix`.

```
public class Node {
    int row;
    int column;
    double value;
    Nodo columnLink;
    Nodo rowLink;
    Nodo nextRowLink;
}

public class Matrix{
    Nodo head;
    Nodo first;
    Nodo last;
}
```

Is it the best way to go? I mean, when it is a head node it doesn't store anything in `value` and when it is a non zero element, it doesn't store anything in `nextRowLink`. I'm asking about the memory use since the purpose of sparce matrix are to not use unnesessary space in memory. What implies `nextRowLink = null;`?, `value` is a native variable so, it takes 64 bits even if it is `value = 0 or Double.NaN;`.

Is it a better way than the one I'm thinking on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this: a linked list of linked lists

```
class SparseMatrix {
    ColumnNode head;
    int dimx, dimy;
    // other members
}

class ColumnNode {
    int colNum;
    RowNode head;
    ColumnNode next;
}

class RowNode {
    int rowNum;
    double value;
    RowNode next;
}
```

which has slightly "slimmer" nodes, is easier to get right with the help of the type system, and allows you to skip the unnecessary "head" nodes by using the `head` pointers.

If you know each row (column) contains at least one value, switch to an array of column (row) lists.

Comment: The last RowNode must be linked to a ColumnNode, there is a problem since they are different classes, no? look at the figure(http://books.google.com/books?id=gMcmb-qYODUC&lpg=PR3&dq=roberto%20florez%20algoritmos&hl=es&pg=PA108#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Roger: you can make both types of list cyclic if you want, just like in the picture: point the last `RowNode`'s `next` to the first `RowNode` in its column. That would require empty nodes to support empty rows/columns, though. (I don't see what algorithm would benefit from this setup...)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a parent class `Nodo` that contains neither a `value` field nor a `nextRowLink` field. Then you can define two subclasses: `RowHead` that has a `nextRowLink` and `NodoConData` that has a `value` field. Use the first one for the row head and the other for the rest of the nodes on the row.

Comment: The last NodoConData must be linked to a RowHead, they have the same parent class, but, isn't there a problem? How about the later questions? What is the use of memory of `nextRowLink = null;` and the one with the double object.